# Strange behavior of Textfield in SwiftUI while converting data in UTC and viceversa

Tags: swift, swiftui, time, textfield, formatter

I have created 2 custom Textfield next to each other in an Hstack where the user can insert a custom formatted time,
the first one accepts local hours and converts the time in UTC time and publishes this value to a bind variable UTCtime, the second text field does exactly the same but the opposite allows the user to text in the UTCtime and publish the converted time in local time to a bind var localTime.

Basically my user has to be able to type in local time and automatically get UTC time and if he type in UTC time he gets Local time.

Here is the issue:
As you can see from the gif.. I’m pressing the del key to delete second value.. but it does not delate.

[image: ss]

I’m getting very strange behavior when I type in the value or when I’m trying to delete the value from the second text field it does not allow me to delete, probably because the first text field is publishing the result to the bind var of the second text field, how can solve this issue?

```
Section("Time Selection"){

                    
   
                    HStack{
                        
                        Text("Time")
                        
                        TimeTextFieldLocal(timeLocal: $localTime, timeInUTC: $utcTime, description: "Local")
                        TimeTextFieldUTC(timeLocal: $localTime, timeInUTC: $utcTime, description: "UTC")
                       
                        
                    }
                  
                }



struct TimeTextFieldLocal: View {
    @Binding var timeLocal: String
    @Binding var timeInUTC: String
    var description: String
    var body: some View {
        TextField(description, text: $timeLocal)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .textContentType(.none)
            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            .onChange(of: timeLocal) { oldValue, newValue in
                timeLocal = formatTimeInput(newValue)
                timeInUTC = timeLocal.toUTC()
            }
    }

    
    private func formatTimeInput(_ input: String) -> String {
        let allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789")

        // Remove non-numeric characters
        let numericString = input.components(separatedBy: allowedCharacterSet.inverted).joined()

        // Limit the input to 4 digits
        let limitedString = String(numericString.prefix(4))

        // Insert colons at appropriate positions (e.g., 2230 -> 22:30)
        let formattedString: String
        if limitedString.count > 2 {
            let index = limitedString.index(limitedString.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)
            let hour = limitedString[..<index]
            let minute = limitedString[index...]
            formattedString = "\(hour):\(minute)"
        } else {
            formattedString = limitedString
        }

        return formattedString
    }
    
}

struct TimeTextFieldUTC: View {
    @Binding var timeLocal: String
    @Binding var timeInUTC: String
    var description: String
    var body: some View {
        TextField(description, text: $timeInUTC)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .textContentType(.none)
            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
            .onChange(of: timeInUTC) { oldValue, newValue in
                timeInUTC = formatTimeInput(newValue)
                timeLocal = timeInUTC.toCurrent()
            }
    }

    
    private func formatTimeInput(_ input: String) -> String {
        let allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789")

        // Remove non-numeric characters
        let numericString = input.components(separatedBy: allowedCharacterSet.inverted).joined()

        // Limit the input to 4 digits
        let limitedString = String(numericString.prefix(4))

        // Insert colons at appropriate positions (e.g., 2230 -> 22:30)
        let formattedString: String
        if limitedString.count > 2 {
            let index = limitedString.index(limitedString.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)
            let hour = limitedString[..<index]
            let minute = limitedString[index...]
            formattedString = "\(hour):\(minute)"
        } else {
            formattedString = limitedString
        }

        return formattedString
    }
    
}


extension String {
    func toUTC()->String{
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        let convertDate = formatter.date(from: self) ?? Date.now
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        let convertDateTo = formatter.string(from: convertDate) 
        
        return convertDateTo
    }
    func toCurrent()->String{
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        let convertDate = formatter.date(from: self) ?? Date.now
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        let convertDateTo = formatter.string(from: convertDate)
        return convertDateTo
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is caused by your use of Bindings in a  "two-way" style, where output directly has side effects on the input (which will be rendered), which in turn has side effects on the output, and so forth. Use Bindings such, that any setter routes the value _first_ through your logic (i.e. setup a function `(Value) -> Void` in the Binding for the setter), which calculates a new whole state and from that, calculate the new view state (text) which are set in the bindings.